# Running router out of its case

Tags: wireless, safety, shielding

I'm currently building a robot, and as part of its spec it must connect to a wifi network. I have a Belkin wireless router, which I have taken out of its case to expose the PCB.

My question is:

Is it dangerous to run the wireless router when its out of its case, as the case provided some sort of shielding? I am only 16 and studying electronics, so I am not really sure if the plastic router case actually sheilds anything, or is only there to house the electronics...

Answer (score 4):

About the only thing I would consider "dangerous" in a router would be the wall power.  If your router is powered from a wall wart, as many of them are, then there is little that can hurt you inside the case.

I doubt the case was ever any kind of shield.  At best it was a mechanical barrier to prevent dirt from getting in and things falling onto the circuitry that could cause shorts or whatever.

Keep in mind that the router will produce a relatively strong radio field in the immediate vicinity of its antenna.  Too much metal nearby the antenna can reflect and refract the radio waves, and de-tune the antenna.  This effectively means the range will be reduced, but this probably won't matter if the robot is not operating at the fringes of the access point's range.

The radio field can also interfere with other nearby eletronics.  Try to keep the antenna above and away from other electronic things.

Answer (score 2):

The plastic casing adds safety in the obvious sense of preventing one from touching Mains-AC-levels and likewise that one's hands won't cause electrostatic damage to the sensitive parts. But aside from that, if you are careful about what you are doing with the PCB itself, you should be fine without the case.

However, do verify for your project's sake that removing the housing on your specific router doesn't remove any of the FUNCTIONALITY, i.e., in case there are any components that are attached to the case.

Answer (score 1):

No the plastic doesn't shield, and you can use it out of the case. If it had shielding it would look like a thin aluminum foil. Since it doesn't seem to have that it will comply with FCC/EU regulations without it, and will so out of its case too.

Comment: Couldn't the plastic be treated with some EMI shielding substance? From what I can see, that's common practice with say plastic laptop cases.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I don't know if it would be cheaper than the foil. Think about connecting to the circuit's ground, which IMHO would be easier for foil.

Comment: I've seen that problem solved using threaded metal inserts. They too are covered by the conductive material and screws inserted into them mate with ground points on the PCB. The foil would probably be cheaper, but inside laptops, I've only seen it used for heat conduction.